# Internal templated class c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested, internal

I'm trying this little exercice from my c++ class and i've manage to do this from now.

It's not fully completed, but for now i'm facing the eternal problem of template of internal class.

I've seen a lot of different solution here on stack and on other websites, but still missing someting.
+ my goal at the end is also to understand the "why".

It's an Iterator internal class needed to iterate to my array. I've seen some exemple giving 2 differents typename for External and Iternal class and then using the typedef, but i'm not sure what's the best way to implement it.

As you can understand my Iterator class need to take the same kind of type as my Array class.

I for sure will need to change some function signatures and add some <\T> here and there, but for now i just need to avoid all the template traps.

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Iterator;

template<typename T>
class Array{

    T* _data;
    size_t _size;
    Iterator* _start;

public:

    class Iterator{
        T* content;

    public:
        explicit Iterator(T* value):content(value){}

        Iterator& operator++(){
            ++content;
            return *this;
        }

        T* operator*(){
            return content;
        }

        bool operator ==(const Iterator& o)const{
            if(content == o.content){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool operator !=(const Iterator& o)const{
            return !(*this == o);
        }
    };


    Array(const size_t s):_size(s){
        _data = new T[_size]();
        _start = new Iterator(_data);
    }

    Array(const Array& o):_size(o._size), _data(o._data), _start(o._start){}

    Array(const std::initializer_list<T>& list):_size(list.size()){
        auto start = list.begin();
        auto fin = list.end();

        _data = new T[_size];

        size_t index = 0;
        while(start != fin){
        _data[index++] = *start++;
        }

        _start = new Iterator(_data);
    }

    virtual ~Array(){
        cout << "~Array" << endl;
        delete[] _data;
    }

    Array<T>& operator= (const Array& o){
        if(this != &o){
            delete[] _data;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < o._size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = o._data[i];
            }
            _size = o._size;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T& operator[](const size_t index){
        if(index < _size){
            return *_data[index];
        }
    }

    const size_t size()const{
        return _size;
    }

    Iterator begin(){
        return Iterator(_data[0]);
    }

    Iterator end(){
        return Iterator(_data[_size-1]);
    }

};
```

Can you please give me a clue or help me with this.

For more here is my basic main:

```
#include "Array.h"

int main() {

    Array<string> array({"h","e","l","l","o"});

    for (Array<string>::Iterator i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is "the eternal problem of template of internal class" ? Does this not compile?

Comment: You are confusing the compiler by having two different `Iterator` types. There is no way to forward declare a nested type outside the class, so skip that. You could rathe move the `private` section to the end of the class, so that the nested `Iterator` is visible.

Comment: what is the difference between your `_start` and your `_data`, form my understanding they have different type but represent the same thing

Comment: @Tyker kind of, _data is my array container (that is a pointer to the first case of the array), and start is an Iterator pointing to the first case of _data, used to iterate through it.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you, it think it was my major mistake. I edited it and deleted this _start Iterator using the function start() to return it. A bit eavier because start() always need to calculate it, but for this exercice it will be ok. Thank you

Comment: Your code will suffer from dangling pointers, as the copy constructor simply copies the pointer, yet the destructor (of the copied-from `Array`) deletes the memory pointed to, leaving the copied-to `Array` with a dangling pointer. Horrible. Moreover, there is no need for member `Array::start`, the memory of which, btw, is leaked (never de-allocated).

Comment: Thank you @Walter you're right, i didn't see it, because in the program i wrote, i never deal with a situation where the array that i copy is deleted before the copied array. I changed it in the corrected code down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no template `Iterator` at the global scope, so this is wrong:

```
template <typename T>
class Iterator;
```

Also, `Array<T>::Iterator` isn't a template, it's just an inner class. You can simply forward-declare it inside the class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Array {
public:
    class Iterator;
```

Then there are some bugs in your code (e.g. `end()` should be 1 past the last element, you need to dereference the iterator twice and construct one from a pointer).

Here's a fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Array {

    T* _data;
    size_t _size;
public:
    class Iterator;
private:
    Iterator* _start;

public:

    class Iterator {
        T* content;

    public:
        explicit Iterator(T* value) :content(value) {}

        Iterator& operator++() {
            ++content;
            return *this;
        }

        T* operator*() {
            return content;
        }

        bool operator ==(const Iterator& o)const {
            if (content == o.content) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool operator !=(const Iterator& o)const {
            return !(*this == o);
        }
    };


    Array(const size_t s) :_size(s) {
        _data = new T[_size]();
        _start = new Iterator(_data);
    }

    Array(const Array& o) :_size(o._size), _data(o._data), _start(o._start) {}

    Array(const std::initializer_list<T>& list) :_size(list.size()) {
        auto start = list.begin();
        auto fin = list.end();

        _data = new T[_size];

        size_t index = 0;
        while (start != fin) {
            _data[index++] = *start++;
        }

        _start = new Iterator(_data);
    }

    virtual ~Array() {
        cout << "~Array" << endl;
        delete[] _data;
    }

    Array<T>& operator= (const Array& o) {
        if (this != &o) {
            delete[] _data;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < o._size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = o._data[i];
            }
            _size = o._size;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T& operator[](const size_t index) {
        if (index < _size) {
            return *_data[index];
        }
    }

    const size_t size()const {
        return _size;
    }

    Iterator begin() {
        return _start;
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return Iterator(_data + _size);
    }

};

int main() {
    Array<string> array({ "h","e","l","l","o" });

    for (Array<string>::Iterator i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); ++i)
        cout << **i << endl;
}
```

Comment: PS: I don't know what `_start` is for, it's unused. I left it in there just in case.

Comment: of sorry yes was wrong, _start is endeed what i will return from the begin() method in the Array class

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @rustyx for your help,
Wasn't far from it, but realy thank you.

I will post my corrected and working code here in case it can help others.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template<typename T>
class Array{

T* _data;
size_t _size;

public:

    class Iterator{
        T* content;

    public:
        explicit Iterator(T* value):content(value){}

        Iterator& operator++(){
            ++content;
            return *this;
        }

        T& operator*(){
            return *content;
        }

        bool operator ==(const Iterator& o)const{
            if(content == o.content){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool operator !=(const Iterator& o)const{
            return !(*this == o);
        }
    };


Array(const size_t s):_size(s){
    _data = new T[_size]();
}

Array(const Array& o):_size(o._size){
    _data = new T[_size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < o._size; ++i) {
        _data[i] = o._data[i];
    }
}

Array(const std::initializer_list<T>& list):_size(list.size()){
    auto start = list.begin();
    auto fin = list.end();

    _data = new T[_size];

    size_t index = 0;
    while(start != fin){
        _data[index++] = *start++;
    }

}

virtual ~Array(){
    cout << "~Array" << endl;
    delete[] _data;
}

Array<T>& operator= (const Array& o){
    if(this != &o){
        delete[] _data;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < o._size; ++i) {
            _data[i] = o._data[i];
        }
        _size = o._size;
    }

    return *this;
}

T& operator[](const size_t index){
    if(index < _size){
        return *_data[index];
    }
}

const size_t size()const{
    return _size;
}

Iterator begin(){
    return Iterator(_data);
}

Iterator end(){
    return Iterator(_data + _size);
}

};
```